# Filtering gridview by 2 controls (dropdownlists)

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, ms-access

I have a listview on my page which I would like filtered by two dropdownlists, now I have implemented both the listview and the controls.

What I have found is that both controls cannot work at the same time. The first control will work fine, however the second will not regardless of whether the first control is set or not (defaulted to show all).

Is there any way round this? Below I have written the code I am using in VS along with the C# code.

**Visual Studio**

```
    <asp:AccessDataSource ID="AccessDataSource1" runat="server" 
        DataFile="~/App_Data/ASPNetDB.mdb" 
        SelectCommand="SELECT * FROM [Library]">
        <SelectParameters>
            <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="SideContent:DropDownList1" Name="Category" 
                PropertyName="SelectedValue" Type="String" DefaultValue="" />
            <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="SideContent:DropDownList2" Name="Region" 
                PropertyName="SelectedValue" Type="String" DefaultValue="" />
        </SelectParameters>
    </asp:AccessDataSource>

Category:
<asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList1" runat="server"
        DataSourceID="AccessDataSource2" DataTextField="CatName" 
        DataValueField="CatID" AppendDataBoundItems="true" AutoPostBack="true" 
        onselectedindexchanged="DropDownList1_SelectedIndexChanged">
            <asp:ListItem Value="0" Selected ="True" >All Categories</asp:ListItem>
</asp:DropDownList>

    <asp:AccessDataSource ID="AccessDataSource2" runat="server" 
        DataFile="~/App_Data/ASPNetDB.mdb" SelectCommand="SELECT * FROM [CategoryTable]">
    </asp:AccessDataSource>

Region:
    <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList2" runat="server" 
        DataSourceID="AccessDataSource3" DataTextField="RegionName" 
        DataValueField="RegionID" AppendDataBoundItems="true" AutoPostBack="true"  
        onselectedindexchanged="DropDownList2_SelectedIndexChanged">
        <asp:ListItem Value="0" Selected ="True" >All Regions</asp:ListItem>
    </asp:DropDownList>
    <asp:AccessDataSource ID="AccessDataSource3" runat="server" 
        DataFile="~/App_Data/ASPNetDB.mdb" 
        SelectCommand="SELECT * FROM [RegionsTable]">
    </asp:AccessDataSource>
```

**C#**

```
protected void DropDownList1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    var Category = DropDownList1.SelectedValue;
    int intCategory = Convert.ToInt16(Category);

    if (intCategory> 0)
    {
        AccessDataSource1.SelectCommand = "SELECT * FROM [CategoryTable] WHERE ([Category] = ?)";
    }
    else
    {
        AccessDataSource1.SelectCommand = "SELECT * FROM [CategoryTable]";
    }

}

protected void DropDownList2_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    var Region = DropDownList2.SelectedValue;
    int intRegion = Convert.ToInt16(Region);

    if (intRegion > 0)
    {
        AccessDataSource1.SelectCommand = "SELECT * FROM [RegionTable] WHERE ([Region] = ?)";
        //Response.Write(intRegion);
    }
    else
    {
        AccessDataSource1.SelectCommand = "SELECT * FROM [RegionTable]";
    }

}
```

Comment: What **exactly** do you mean both control can't work at the same time ?

Comment: So lets say I select England in the Country dropdownlist, this will work. But if I select anything from the Region dropdownlist irrespective of whether whats selected in the Country dropdownlist. Region only works if I take out the Country control parameter from the AccessDataSource.

Answer (score 1):

C#:

```
int category = 0, region = 0;
    protected void DropDownList1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        var Category = DropDownList1.SelectedValue;
        int intCategory = Convert.ToInt16(Category);
        category = intCategory;
        if (category > 0)
        {
            if (region > 0)
            {
                AccessDataSource1.SelectCommand = "SELECT * FROM [CategoryTable] WHERE ([Category] = ?) AND ([Region]) = ?";
            }
            else
            {
                AccessDataSource1.SelectCommand = "SELECT * FROM [CategoryTable] WHERE ([Category] = ?)";
            }
        }
        else
        {
            AccessDataSource1.SelectCommand = "SELECT * FROM [CategoryTable]";
        }

    }

    protected void DropDownList2_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        var Region = DropDownList2.SelectedValue;
        int intRegion = Convert.ToInt16(Region);
        region = intRegion;
        if (region > 0)
        {
            if (category > 0)
            {
                AccessDataSource1.SelectCommand = "SELECT * FROM [RegionTable] WHERE ([Region] = ?) AND ([Category]) = ?";
            }
            else
            {
                AccessDataSource1.SelectCommand = "SELECT * FROM [RegionTable] WHERE ([Region] = ?)";
            }
            //Response.Write(intRegion);
        }
        else
        {
            AccessDataSource1.SelectCommand = "SELECT * FROM [RegionTable]";
        }

    }
```

Comment: So this code deals more with what happens if both dropdowns have been changed, this is not the issue I am having. What the issue is exactly is that DropDownList2 will not filter the results, its not anything to do with the code for DropDownList2 because I have tried taking out the control parameter of ListView for DropDownList1 and then DropDownList2 works fine.